# Why don't my Javascript prompts show up from my Express.IO .ejs file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, express.io

I am relatively new to JavaScript and subsequently Node + Express.IO. I am trying to build a page that will track in real time connections made by different 'users' to the server. Consequently, when I do include all the functions from the io module, my prompt() and alert do not work anymore. I am running `nodemon app.js` from my terminal and no compilation errors are showing up when I do so. The alert and prompt work again when I remove all the io functions.

These are the contents of my index.ejs `<body>` tag:

```
<body>
<h1>Chatroom</h1>
<script>
    alert("Hello!");
    var name = prompt("What is your name?");
    io.connect();
    io.emit.('got_a_new_user', {name: name});  
    io.on('new_user', function(data) {
    //render this new info in the HTML
         var users = data.users;
         console.log(users);
             if (users != undefined) {
                console.log("\n\n\n" + users);
             // if users is defined, append the new division containing the username
         }
    });
    io.on('disconnect_user', function(data) {
    var users = data.users;
             if (users != undefined) {
                 // If users is defined remove the corresponding HTML element
             }       
    });
</script>
<div id="container">
</div>
</body>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, could you show how you are including the io module? It should be something like this: `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` where src corresponds to your server's folder structure.
Also you cannot do `io.on(...)`, instead you need to do the following: `var socket = io.connect` and then `socket.on(...)`

Comment: It seems that my problem was quite trivial, there was an extra period following the emit() function. 'io.emit.('got_a_new_user', {name: name});' should have been 'io.emit('got_a_new_user', {name: name});'. Thanks to all who replied.

Answer (score 0):

Adding example for the comment added by UKatz,

You will have to connect `socket.io` from the client as follows,

index.ejs

```
<script src="http://ip:port/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     var socket = io.connect('http://ip:port');
     socket.emit('got_a_new_user', {name: name});  
</script>
```

Check [socket.io](http://socket.io/) documentation for how to connect socket.io with client.